# GoogleAnalyticsでカスタムディメンションの値の収集が上手くいっていない

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

GoogleAnalyticsを利用してWordpressサイトの分析を行っており、
WordpressのユーザーIDをカスタムディメンションとして収集しているのですが、
海外の一部ユーザー(カルフォルニア州等)からの値の収集が上手くいっていないようです。
これはGoogleAnalyticsの地域毎の制限が原因なのでしょうか？
それとも別の原因があるのでしょうか？
ご存知の方がいらっしゃるなら教えて頂けると幸いです

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/12re6gtuzuty3w) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)